# Key "productTitle" for array with keys "0, catTitle" does not exist in EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm trying to join two tables and print a value in twig template but I'm having this issue.

This is my Controller action.

```
/**
     * @Route("products/display/{id}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function displayAction($id) {

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('p, pc.catTitle')
                ->from('EagleShopBundle:Products', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('EagleShopBundle:ProductCategory', 'pc', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pc.id = p.category')
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.id', '?5'))
                ->setParameter(5, $id);

        $product = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

        return $this->render("EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig", array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'image_path' => '/bundles/eagleshop/images/'
        ));
    }
```

This is my twig file line related to the issue,

```
<h1>{{product.productTitle}}</h1>
```

I guess issue is related to this line

> $qb->select('p, pc.catTitle')

This is the error I get,

> Key "productTitle" for array with keys "0, catTitle" does not exist in
>   EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig

Comment: Do you have a relation between this two entities? Maybe you can paste `Products` entity code in here?

Comment: Yes and when I try $qb->select('p.productTitle, pc.catTitle') it works. But I need other fileds too...

Comment: Ok, give me some minutes - I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try next query:

```
$qb->select('p, partial pc.{id, catTitle}') 
                // if you need full productCategory object then write just 'p, pc'
            ->from('EagleShopBundle:Products', 'p')
            ->leftJoin('p.category', 'pc') 
               //productCategory is the field 
               //in product entity which has relation to product category entity, 
               //paste your field (not column!) name here 
               //if it is not productCategory
            ->where('p.id = :productId')
            ->setParameter('productId', $id);
```

P.S.
It is better to move queries to entity repositories :)

P.P.S. 
[Doctrine partial objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)

**UPD**
Fixed query - with right field name

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm having this issue,  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 96 near 'pc WHERE p.id': Error: Class Eagle\ShopBundle\Entity\Products has no association named productCategory

Comment: You said that you have relation between entities. So, could you paster `Products` entity code - I need only field definitions + their annotations.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, as I said in answer if you field name in `Product` entity which is relation to `ProductCategory` entity is not `productCategory`, you must write your own name. As I now see - you have stated in your question that you field name is `category`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Still 'Method "catTitle" for object "Eagle\ShopBundle\Entity\Products" does not exist in EagleShopBundle:global:product.html.twig' this issue comes really sorry I'm totally new to this Partial Objects concept.

Comment: As objects are related and you joined one to another in your query, it is not like in sql - result fields will be on the same level. With doctrine if you join one to another you must go like through some kind of tree of relations. In you case, I think, for catTitle, it would be something like this: `{{ product.category.catTitle }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101855/discussion-between-vimuth-and-ilya-yarkovets).